# MSB ADC to LSB DSP

Tags: audio, embedded, texas-instruments

I'm currently in the process of designing a digital audio mixer and I'm not the most experienced when it comes to embedded systems.

I'm using a PCM 4201 ADC http://www.ti.com/product/PCM4201/description and I notice that it outputs left/right justified 24 bit MSB data. This sounds pretty good but the processor I want to use, the DM3730 processor http://www.ti.com/product/DM3730/description happens to use LSB data. Is this a problem or is there an easy way to convert this without introducing latency?

Comment: Different platform endianness must be managed. Somewhere you'll have to menage the conversion. Maybe into TX/RX data interrupt on ARM side. DMAs and data buffering will be required to reduce the latency as low as possible.

Comment: Generally on the processor you'll be able to configure the serial peripheral to receive data as either MSB or LSB, at which point it received data will be in the native format of the processor.

Comment: @Ross Thanks, I'll look into to that.